# Python check if key1 or key2 exists in directory

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to check something like this:

```
if ('key1' or 'key2') in my_dictionary:
    dosmth()
```

How can I do that ? The above code doesn't seem to work. It seems like it takes into account only 'key1', so the syntax must be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the `'key1' or 'key2'` part would first be evaluated. It will always produce `key1`:

```
>>> 'key1' or 'key2'
'key1'
```

Instead, you meant to:

```
if 'key1' in my_dictionary or 'key2' in my_dictionary:
```

---

To scale the problem to N keys, use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
if any(key in my_dictionary for key in keys):
    # ...
```

Comment: any better way to do this considering I will have about 15 values to check ?